# Analyze all functions with radare2

Tags: binary-analysis, radare2

I have a big library in which IDA found ~84300 functions but using `aa` in radare2 I was just able to found ~3000.

I tried setting `anal.hasnext` to `true`, `anal.from` and `anal.to` to the start and the end of the .text section but with not luck

So is there an optimal way to analyze all the functions using radare?

By optimal I mean avoiding xrefs or other analyzis

Thanks

Comment: You can try to use `aab` as it's quite fast and does not handle xrefs.

Comment: It worked, can you create an answer so I can mark it as answered

Comment: I'm sorry some functions that were correctly analyzed before now are just a bunch of `add byte [eax], al`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the help of analysis you can use `aa?`. For a more detailed information i would always suggest visiting the sourcecode as a lot of `aa` commands are combinations of different steps. A good starting point is at `libr/core/cmd_anal.c`

`aab` instead is a total different approach and can create a lot of false positives.

You could also give `aaa` a try but i assume that will take some time to finish.